# Understanding Transaction In Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, transactions

I have a script that saves user addresses during order process. If a customer want to add new address i'm showing a form and handle this process with ajax.

When saving address successful, i'm hiding the form.

Here is my code.

```
//Save Address
DB::beginTransaction();
try
{
    $addressData['new_address_id'] = $this->insertAddress($addressData);

    if($addressData['default_address'] == 1)
    {
        (new Address)->removeDefaultAddress(Auth::user()->id);
        (new Address)->assignDefaultAddress(Auth::user()->id, $addressData['new_address_id']);
    }

    DB::commit();

    if(!is_null($addressData['new_address_id']))
    {
        Session::put('order_delivery_address', $addressData['new_address_id']);
    }
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'addressData' => $addressData], 200);
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    DB::rollback();

    throw $e;

    Session::forget('order_delivery_address');

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'false',
        'errors'  => trans('main.db_unknown_exception'),
    ], 422);
}
```

I think that i didn't understand db transactions. Because if there is a problem with transaction we are catch exception. But new address form is hiding. Because http respond 200 is returns.

I think i wrote it in wrong places.

Comment: Don't throw the exception again. Catch it, rollback the DB, then do your processing.